# How to get default values for nested objects including zero as a value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Get default values for `x`:

```
let defaultX = 3;
function vec1({ x }) {
  x = x || defaultX;
  return { x };
}
```

Usage fails for:

```
vec1({ x: 0 }); // returns { x: 3 }, expected: { x: 0 }
```

Comment: 0 evaluates to `false`. You could use `!isNaN(x)` instead maybe

Comment: `x = x === 0 ? 0 : x || defaultX;`

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) for an undefined property.

```js
let defaultX = 3;

function vec1({ x = defaultX }) {
    return { x };
}

console.log(vec1({ x: 0 })); // { x: 0 }
console.log(vec1({}));       // { x: 3 }
```